# "Not like that" and "such"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, idioms

Is it possible to say so, meaning "like this"?

> I know I used to be selfish, but I'm not ***like that*** anymore.
>
> I know I used to be selfish, but I'm ***not such*** anymore.

Comment: You don't actually need *anything* between ***not*** and ***anymore***. But imho, idiomatically, ***like that*** is better than ***so***, which is better than ***such***. I'm not sure, but I *think* most native speakers would be more accepting of ***such*** if it referred back to a ***noun*** rather than an adjective *(He used to be **a selfish man**, but he's not such anymore).* It's undeniably clunky though, so best avoid ***such*** altogether in such contexts.

Answer (score 1):

```
I know I used to be selfish, but I'm not like that anymore.
```

^ That is correct and sounds natural.

```
I know I used to be selfish, but I'm not such anymore.
```

^ That is not correct use, it sounds "wrong" but it is intelligible - a listener will know what you mean.

You could say:

```
I know I used to be, but I'm not such a selfish person anymore.
```

In that sentence, "such a " is a complete clause that can be used in that place.  "Such" by itself is not.

```
I know I used to be selfish, but I'm not that way anymore.
I know I used to be selfish, but I'm not anymore.
```

^ Both of those are also correct and natural.